# Refresh iframe on already selected tab on click

Tags: angularjs, iframe, ionic-framework, ionic-view

I have an Ionic 1.x app with the tabs template, on each view of each tab I have an iframe. The thing is that when on the iframe user navigates if he clicks on the current tab again I want to refresh my iframe with the initial url, is this possible?

I already have this on my tabs.html view:

```
<ion-tab title="Home" icon-off="ion-home" icon-on="ion-home" on-select="refresh('home')" href="#/tab/home">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-home"></ion-nav-view>
</ion-tab>
```

on my tab-home.html:

```
<ion-view cache-view="false" hide-nav-bar="true" view-title="Dashboard">
  <ion-content overflow-scroll="false">
    <style>
      #contenedor{width: calc( 100% + 0px) ; height: 100%!important; overflow: hidden !important;}
      iframe{width: calc( 100% + 17px) ; height: 100%;}
    </style>
    <div id="contenedor" style="overflow:auto;-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch">
    <iframe id="iframehome" style="width:100%;height:100%" type="text/html" ng-src="{{direhome | trusted}}"></iframe>
    </div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

and on my controller (nothing of this works on current tab is clicked):

```
.controller('HomeCtrl', function($scope) {
 console.log("homectrl");
 $scope.direhome = "http://google.com/";
  $scope.refresh = function(){
    $window.location.reload(true)
    $state.go($state.current, {}, {reload: true});
  }
})
```

Thanks you!

Comment: id try dropping the iframe into a directive and remove it on refresh then add it back.

Comment: @alphapilgrim mm how I drop efficiently the directive and bring it back? never did before